# Emulating onbeforeunload and onunload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, onbeforeunload, onunload

I am testing `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` message mechanism on different browsers, for mobile testing I normally use chrome emulator. However when I try to simulate `onbeforeunload` event by refreshing chrome window when emulation is on I get Chrome 'Confirm reload?' dialog.

[image]

These dialogs differ from browser to browser and I think chrome is not emulating this properly.
(I would expect it to be similar to Safari)    [image]

**How do I test `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` mechanisms for multiple mobile devices?**

Comment: The behaviour you are observing is correct - each browser handles onbeforeunload in its own way and shows specific window. Chrome shows the window with text you are seeing and it it the counterpart of Safari one. Please note that windows shown on these events are browser-specific and can't be 100% customized so you will always have "Confirm reload" text in Chrome.

Comment: @SzybkiSasza Hi, indeed I would be expecting dialog to look different on Chrome when emulator is on, but like you said each is different and chrome shows it's own dialog rather one that is being emulated. So I am looking for method or mechanism to test these things.

Comment: To be honest - you probably can't do this in a simple way. If you have Android-powered device and about 5-10 minutes spare time, you could try to use https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging on real device. It is simple to set and allows you to tunnel your computer deployment for use on mobile device and to control and debug mobile browser in PC Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able do this with the [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

```
$('#buttonFoo').click(function(){
    $(window).trigger('beforeunload');
});
```

Just connect that to a button and you should be good to go

Comment: Sorry does not simulate event properly it steps into function but does not show `Confirm reload` dialog when invoked with button, displays dialog fine with F5.

Comment: Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wnuLdw4t/1/ to simulate F5 click 'Update' in jsfiddle menu. I must compliment it was a very clever try. :)

Comment: Very interesting. You're right, it does everything except show the dialog.

Comment: Also, I can't leave a comment on the original post, but I may have misunderstood your original request. Are you looking for Chrome's emulator to show you the Safari/Firefox/IE/etc dialog boxes? The Chrome emulator is only for layout and is not 100% accurate either. I used it for testing a webpage layout on an iPad, but when I loaded the page on actual iPad there were some minuscule differences.

Comment: I am not very picky any solution will be much appreciated (With chrome of without). What I am looking for is way to test these on mobile preferably without having to have each of devices at hand.

Comment: The [Android emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) will probably help for testing Android devices. If you're on a Mac, you can install Xcode and use the iPhone Simulator (a quick Google search shows iOS simulators for Windows, but I'm sure of the legitimacy or price of them).